# Can I write SD card a cluster without erasing if it contains only 0xFF?

Tags: flash, sd

In my understanding, a block has many clusters in it. Once I erase a block, all data in the block became 0xFF. Then I can write new data into the clusters in the block.

So, if I already know that all data in the cluster is 0xFF, is it necessary to erase it again? Can I just write data without erasing? Is that a standard behavior defined somewhere?

Comment: TLDR: Yes, you can.

Comment: "_Can I just write data without erasing?_" - you're not responsible for managing this... erasing the blocks, maintaining a logical-to-physical map, and much more is taken care of for you by the SD card. I'd expect that whether or not the card will "_know_" there's no need to do anything in this situation (and take the shortcut) will be implementation defined. There is an MMC_ERASE command, which behaves similarly to TRIM, but not all cards will support it, and not all readers will offer translation (e.g: from TRIM to MMC_ERASE for USB devices).

Comment: You don't need to manage an SD card like "raw" flash. When you want to write to it somewhere, just do that. The SD card's built in flash management controller will decide if it needs to erase anything 1st or not.